# error in hitting the angular routes using nodejs server

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript

I have my homepage at `locahost:3000`, and there is a link in my homepage to login page at `/login`.

When I clicked at that link, It reaches to the login page. But when I refresh that page it shows error `Cannot GET /login`. Again when I am clicking on that link from homepage, it reaches to login page But when I am trying to enter the url `localhost:3000/login` it gives same error `Cannot GET /login`.

My `app.js` is -

```
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/dist/newApp'));

    app.get('/', (req,res)=>{
      res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, ''));
    });
```

and my angular routes is  -

```
export const myRoutes: Routes = [
   {
    path: ' ',
    component: HomepageComponent
   },
  {
    path: 'login',
    component: LoginComponent
  }]
```

And I am using `routerLink="/login"` instead of `href` for the link.

I don't know why this is happening.

My server running process is -- `npm build` and `then npm start`

And If I am running my angular server as `ng serve`, and then enter the url `localhost:3000/login` directly in browser, it is working.

But When I am running nodejs server it again causing problem.

I think the problem is that on running nodejs server, angular server stops runnning.

Can someone explain the reason for this and how to run both the server.

Comment: If your nodejs server is being used to serve the Angular files, you don't need the angular server running. Have you built your Angular app (using `ng build`), and added the `dist` directory to your node app?

Comment: yes,  on running `ng build` It automatically creates `dist` directory

Comment: Okay, so your `sendFile` function needs to point at the `index.html` file within your dist directory. You may find it easier the use the `static` function, as the browser will need access to all of the files within that directory

Comment: yes, I am using that, I have updated my `app.js` in above query, You can check that.

Comment: Okay, so your index.html file is within `dist/newApp`, yes? If you remove the `app.get('/')` for now, and try to access `localhost:3000/`, does it load your app?

Comment: yes, shows homepage

Comment: Good, nearly there then. I've added an answer below that should help for the `/login` route

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a final `*` route to catch any paths it doesn't recognize (such as `/login`), and return the `index.html` file.

```
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/dist/newApp/index.html'));
});
```

It's very important that you place this after any other route declarations.